# Modify all numbers before insert or update

Tags: sqlalchemy

In SqlAlchemy I use:

```
price = Column(Numeric(18, 5))
```

in various placed throught my app. When I get a number formatted in swedish, with a comma instead of a dot (0,34 instead of 0.34) and try to change the price column the number gets set to 0.00000.

To solve this I have this code:

```
obj.price = price.replace(',','.')
```

But having this all over the code makes it pretty ugly and the risk is that I forget one place. Would it be possible to have some kind of generic converter function which gets called before a value is converted from a string to a Numeric? And that I have that in one place only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `validates` decorator of SQLAlchemy: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapped_attributes.html

> A quick way to add a “validation” routine to an attribute is to use
>   the validates() decorator. An attribute validator can raise an
>   exception, halting the process of mutating the attribute’s value, or
>   can change the given value into something different.

In your case the code could look similar to:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class Obj(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'obj'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    price = Column(Numeric(18, 5))

    @validates('price')
    def validate_price(self, key, price):
        if ',' in price:
            return float(price.replace(',','.'))
        else:
            return float(price)
```